# mkdir is not working properly

Tags: java, ant

I have a properties file which specifies the location of my testcases. The location of     these testcases is specified in the form of relative path with respect to the working copy of   build.xml.

These testcases directories are deleted and created for each run of build. For first run   the build runs correctly but for second run the `mkdir` is not working properly. It throws the   following error:

```
Directory D:\tempt\Tests creation was not successful for an unknown reason
```

My build.properties contain:

```
testcases.location=../../temp/Tests
```

And my target "clean" in build.xml is:

```
<target name="clean" >
    <delete dir="${testcases.location}"  failonerror="false"/>
    <mkdir dir="${testcases.location}"/>
 </target>
```

Here the basedir = `.`
 Please let me know how to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Are you sure the folder is successfully deleted before `<mkdir>`?

Comment: The subdirectory "Tests" gets deleted but not the parent directory.I tried with includeemptydir attribute but then also its not working properly.

Comment: does adding <sequential> help?.

Comment: Try to run your ant build with `ant -v` and check if there is anything  related in the output. Can't reproduce it on my side.